# Listbox can't scroll to the bottom

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, telerik, windows-phone

I notice that when I'm using listbox inside pivot , the listbox won't allow me to see the last item in the listbox but if i remove the pivot then listbox works fine... anyone know how to fix that?

edit:code

```
<phone:Pivot HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource detailPivot}" 
             SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged"
             Margin="0,10,0,0">
    <phone:PivotItem CacheMode="{x:Null}" x:Name="addressPivot"
                     Header="{Binding LocalizedResources.pivotHeader1, 
                              Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" >

        <telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox
            x:Name="AddressListBox"
            ItemsSource="{Binding hereRestAddressDetail}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding hereRestDetail}"
            SelectionChanged="AddressListBox_SelectionChanged" 
            ItemAnimationMode="PlayAll"
            EmptyContent="{Binding}">
            <telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,10">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="10">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}"/>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.by, 
                                                    Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" 
                                           Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding creator}" Margin="-8,0,0,0"
                                           Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextAccentStyle}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding street}"
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                       Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding formatedStreet}" 
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                       Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ratingButton}" Grid.Column="2"
                               Stretch="Uniform" Width="80" Tag="{Binding Id}"
                               Tap="rate_Tap"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ratingValue}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                           TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"
                           Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemTemplate>

            <telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemAddedAnimation>
                <telerikCore:RadMoveYAnimation StartY="500" EndY="0" Duration="0:0:1">
                    <telerikCore:RadMoveYAnimation.Easing>
                        <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                    </telerikCore:RadMoveYAnimation.Easing>
                </telerikCore:RadMoveYAnimation>
            </telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemAddedAnimation>

            <telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.EmptyContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding myMessage}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextGroupHeaderStyle}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.EmptyContentTemplate>

        </telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox>

    </phone:PivotItem>
</phone:Pivot>
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Share the problem with your code

Comment: already added my code

Comment: just give height to the listbox. Its taking an AUTO height

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` on the `RadDataBoundListBox`

This works for me if I use a standard `ListBox` instead of `RadDataBoundListBox`. Is there a reason you're using this control instead of the standard one?